# Alternate way (using Selector) to set up notification observer

Tags: swift, notifications, selector, addobserver

I have successfully setup notification observer using the code below:

```
func setupNotification {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "action:", name: notificationString, object: nil)
}

func action(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Do something when receiving notification
}
```

However, I am not interested in the coding style above since there might be a chance that I could type or copy/paste wrong method name `action:`.

So I tried to `addObserver` in a different way: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector(/* What to pass in here??? */), name: notificationString, object: nil)`, I don't know what to pass in `selector: Selector(...)`.

XCode hints me: `Selector(action(notification: NSNotification)`, but this is illegal.

In Objective C, I can easily pick up a method at this phase but I don't know how in Swift.

Have you tried this syntax? Let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: just use selector: "nameOfYourFunction"

Comment: I did use it, but I just want to try a better way which can help me pick a function from code hint, not copy/paste or type the function.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a Selector is `Selector("action:")`

Comment: So, there is no way to pick `action:` from code hint?

Comment: Not that I know off. `Selector(action)` does not work. It only accepts a string.

Answer (score 0):

Not the direct answer for your question but I have an idea.

In swift instance methods are curried functions that take instance as first argument. Suppose you have a class like this.

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    func bar(notification: NSNotification) {
        // do something with notification
    }
}
```

And somewhere in code you have an instance of `Foo`.

```
let foo = Foo()
```

Now you can get `bar` method as a variable like this

```
let barFunc = Foo.bar(foo)
```

Now imagine in the future `NSNotificationCenter` has an api that lets you assign functions to it instead of selectors.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverFunction(barFunc, name: "notificationName", object: nil)
```

Though I don't like to use `NSNotificationCenter` but It would be nice to see this kind of api in the future.